# Let user choose from much data in database

Tags: database, output

In my database I have 301 'entries' and the user should be able to choose one of them. The problem is, that I don't want to display 301 lines with the name of every entry and a radio box next to it.

So, what is the best way to show such data and let the user choose it? 
The database structure is

```
ID, name, type, country, region, lon, lat, description.
```

Now I need somehow to display it so the user cah choose the correct one to view. But as I said 301 lines are way too much. I thought of drop-down-menus, but this would also be way too much. Any ideas?

Edit: I could do an instant-search but this is just a small task we are going to do here, so the instant-search would be more work than the actual product

Answer (score 0):

The best option would be to have a text input field and make the user choose the name.

Another way to do it is to make multiple pages, you can either display, say 40 entries at a time, or easier, make each one of them represent an alphabetical letter.

Comment: The problem is just, when the user doesn't know the name? And a list of possible entries when I got 300 the user has to search in are a bit too much.

Comment: I don't think your problem has any solution.. If the user doesn't know the name the he has to (1) go through all the users or (2) search his name. In the 1st case, then you have to go with the 300. Or you can display it by small chunks like by country, alphabetical order, etc. Personally , if you only retrieve the names, I don't think your query will be too slow or anything.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for a text entry search with autofill, so that as the user started to type a name, a list of possible matches would be shown.

Comment: Hi, you probably answered, when I was editing. With instant-search I meant auto-fill. It's a nice feature, yes, but for the task I'm doing it is just too much.

Comment: Well, you either provide some form of interactive search, or you display the entire list in some form....I don't see any other way to do it!